# Return column value without aggregation for grouped query

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Ok, question sound very confusing, I just can't come up with better title.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT TS.LocationKey, TA.TrailerKey, MAX(TS.ArrivedOnLocal) MaxArrivedOnLocal
    FROM dbo.DSPTripStop TS
        INNER JOIN dbo.DSPTripAssignment TA ON TS.TripStopKey = TA.ToTripStopKey AND TA.TrailerKey IS NOT NULL        
    GROUP BY TS.LocationKey, TA.TrailerKey
```

Query returns list of trailers with locations and last time they were dropped at that location. This is what I need. MAX(time) for location is a goal.

But I'd like to also know which `DSPTripStop.TripStopKey` this MAX() time happened on.

I can't group by this value. I understand that it is not defined (can be multiple values for the same time). For my purpose ANY random will work. But I can't find any better way then joining second time by `MaxArrivedOnLocal` to get what I need.

SQL Server already "sees" this data when MAX() aggregated, any way to pull it in this query?

Comment: You must join the main table after finding the result set. Then you can get other fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want. Rather than doing a group by, you partition instead, number the rows, then take the top 1

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT TS.LocationKey, 
        TA.TrailerKey, 
        TS.ArrivedOnLocal,
        TS.TripStopKey,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TS.LocationKey, TA.TrailerKey ORDER BY ArrivedOnLocal DESC) rn
    FROM dbo.DSPTripStop TS
    INNER JOIN dbo.DSPTripAssignment TA ON TS.TripStopKey = TA.ToTripStopKey AND TA.TrailerKey IS NOT NULL 
) 
SELECT LocationKey,
    TrailerKey,
    ArrivedOnLocal,
    TripStopKey
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Actually since you say you don't care which value, Rahul's answer is fine. This will be the way to handle it if it does matter

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, but "random" can be fine for duplicate MAX dates, not just random, so Rahul's answer is not fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you need any random value for `DSPTripStop.TripStopKey` then you can use MAX itself as this will return the latest TripStopKey.

```
    SELECT 
        TS.LocationKey, 
        TA.TrailerKey, 
        MAX(TS.ArrivedOnLocal) MaxArrivedOnLocal,
        MAX(TS.TripStopKey)
    FROM dbo.DSPTripStop TS
    INNER JOIN dbo.DSPTripAssignment TA 
    ON TS.TripStopKey = TA.ToTripStopKey 
    AND TA.TrailerKey IS NOT NULL    
GROUP BY TS.LocationKey, TA.TrailerKey
```